# What is the secret unicode key for maas when reconfiguring maas-cluster-controller

Tags: networking, server, apache2, juju, maas

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 server with maas server. I had an issue with rabbitmq message broker and reinstalled it. But it accidentally deleted region-controller settings and when configured again it asked for the secret code. But it doesn't seems to work as the key is not correct for apache server to deploy.
Secret is in the path

```
/var/lib/maas/secret
```

is there a format for this secret key?